# Behavior Transactions PDO::beginTransaction() and "BEGIN"

Tags: mariadb, transaction, php

I have a strange behavior in a php script (PHP 8.1) using MariaDB 10.7.5 database.

This one with native SQL works:

```
$pdo->query("BEGIN");
[ ... some database stuff ... ]
$pdo->query("COMMIT");
```

But using PDO's own function does not work, it results to "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction in xxxx":

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
[ ... some database stuff ... ]
$pdo->commit();
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Were there any DDL statements in the 'stuff'?

Comment: Or any other [statement that causes an implicit commit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-statements-that-cause-an-implicit-commit/)?

Comment: By the way, I edited your question and tags to make it clear that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are different products, not compatible. You shouldn't think of them as variants of the same product.

Comment: @RickJames no statements like this... only some select, updates and inserts... it still works when i use "BEGIN" and "COMMIT", but not when I use the PDO built-In functions.